# Laravel - Call to undefined method Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Swiftmailer to send email. I had installed 
+ "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
+ "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.0".

I create controller and route for it. But it has issue "Call to undefined method Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()". Please check my code and guide me how to fix it? Thanks so much

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_MailTransport;
use Swift_Message;
class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail(){
        // Configuration
        $smtpAddress = 'smtp.zoho.com';
        $port = 465;
        $encryption = 'ssl';
        $yourEmail = 'ptc@gmail.com';
        $yourPassword = '********';

        // Prepare transport
        $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($smtpAddress, $port, $encryption)
                ->setUsername($yourEmail)
                ->setPassword($yourPassword);
        $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        // Prepare content 
        $view = View::make('email_template', [
            'message' => '<h1>Hello World !</h1>'
        ]);

        $html = $view->render();

        // Send email
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('Test')
             ->setFrom(['ptc@gmail.com' => 'Our Code World'])
             ->setTo(["hik@gmail.com" => "mail@mail.com"])
             // If you want plain text instead, remove the second paramter of setBody
             ->setBody($html, 'text/html');

        if($mailer->send($message)){
            echo "Check your inbox";
        }

        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found in GitHub issues, for SwiftMailer "^6.0"

> ::newInstance() method has been deprecated, along with
>   Swift_MailTransport.

Try to change:

```
\Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance() 
\Swift_Mailer::newInstance()
```

to:

```
new \Swift_SmtpTransport();
new \Swift_Mailer()
```

More information about:

- The GitHub [issue](https://github.com/peppeocchi/php-cron-scheduler/commit/c086719a1b0b798cf3320fb5e93a6c806cd31072)
- Documentation for ^6 version, read [Basic Usage](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate things.

You are rewriting something that comes bundled with laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail

No need to setup swiftmailer yourself, just use the laravel classes and set the smtp credentials on

```
config/mail.php
```

It can be as easy as

```
Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
});
```

Or you can go fancy and use a view to make your template.

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    $message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```

Comment: Hi, i had read and knew Laravel had it. But i want to control by myself. Exmap, mailgun give free 10000 emails, but i can't know when it;s gone. So i want to control it

Comment: You don't need to use mailgun, you can use smtp. You could even use your personal gmail to send messages or this zoho account. And yes, there is a way of knowing when you are out of emails on mailgun, it will throw an exception. Then you can use slack, bugsnag or other tool to report that you are out of emails